# How do I use Apache Tailer within a Spring Boot App?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-tailer

## Main Question

I'm writing an app ([available here on GitHub](https://github.com/Ubunfu/mc-log-bot/tree/feature/log-scrapers) - build/run instructions below) that scrapes a log file and reacts to certain events written to the log (in this case, making an HTTP request to a REST API).  I've chosen Java, Spring Boot 2.x, [Apache Tailer](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/input/Tailer.html) and [OpenFeign](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-openfeign) as the primary vehicles to that end.

I suspect I'm not understanding how Apache Tailer and the threading it does in the background work, or how to properly leverage it within a Spring Boot app.  What's a correct way to initialize and run a `Tailer` in the context of a Spring Boot app?

### Additional Info

To test this, I'm starting the app locally, and echoing lines of text into the given log file via a shell. 
As of writing (commit [1fed906](https://github.com/Ubunfu/mc-log-bot/commit/1fed906723ae9bde59a337d40651feb3f0631364)), when I run the app it seems that:

1. The Tailer initializes (I can see [`TailerListenerAdapter.init()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/input/TailerListenerAdapter.html#init(org.apache.commons.io.input.Tailer)) is called on the `TailerListenerAdapter` I constructed it with)
2. The Tailer runs (I see everything I write to the log file it watches passed to [`TailerListenerAdapter.handle()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/input/TailerListenerAdapter.html#handle(java.lang.String))).

As soon as I write something to the log that my TailerListenerAdapter knows it should react to,  it looks like control exits from the `Tailer.run()` method call, and the app exits (gracefully).  I want it to keep running and tailing the log until I stop the app though.

I wasn't really sure where to call `Tailer.run()` in this context so I have it in a `@PostConstruct` method in my custom Tailer subclass. I've never used `@PostConstruct` before, so I'm not 100% sure I'm using it correctly, or if there's a better place to put it to ensure that `run()` gets called at start up while also allowing me to inject all of my my config-file / bean driven options into it.

### Build / Run Instructions

1. Clone the [project](https://github.com/Ubunfu/mc-log-bot)
2. Run this in a shell:
   `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--tailer.logFile=/path/to/any/test.log,--logging.level.com.github.ubunfu.mclogbot=DEBUG`

   OR

   Set up an equivalent run configuration in your IDE. There's an application-local.yml Spring Boot config file with a place to specify the path to the test log file. In IntelliJ, set up a Maven run config with the following in `Command Line`: `spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--spring.profiles.active=local`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure now that the right way to run the `Tailer` in a Spring Boot app is to modify the main class to implement `CommandLineRunner` (as described in this nice little [Mkyong article](https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-non-web-application-example/)), and run the `Tailer` from there.  I believe this is because Spring boot assumes that you're writing a web app where the entry-point is an inbound request to be handled by Tomcat or something.  If you want to change the entry-point (e.g. it's not a web app), you'd do the above and essentially override the default behavior.

Also, I had a problem where the app would stop gracefully unexpectedly after reading a line that was supposed to result in the Feign client making an API call.  It turns out the reason for that was that the Feign client was throwing a `RuntimeException` that I wasn't handling.  It was not immediately apparent that any exception had occurred because there wasn't a stack trace or anything.  I suspect this is because the Tailer is running in another thread? I'm not really sure.  Point is - watch out for that when you're using Tailer!

I hope this helps somebody!